# Как получить урл гиперссылки spreadsheet IOFactory?

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

Всем привет.

Проблема в том что при чтении файла содержащего гиперссылку в ячейке с гиперссылкой я получаю строку"ссылка на сайт" а нужен урл

и уже на этапе `$schdeules = $worksheet->toArray()` массив не содержит ничего кроме текста

```
        /**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
        $inputFileType = IOFactory::identify($file);
        /**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
        $reader = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        /**  Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($file);

        foreach($spreadsheet->getWorksheetIterator() as $sheet => $worksheet) {
            $schdeules = $worksheet->toArray();

            foreach ($schdeules as $row_key => $single_schedule) {

                foreach ($single_schedule as $key_coll => $single_item) {
                    if (!empty(trim($single_item))) {

                        /** собираем названия заголовков */
                        if ($row_key == 0) {
                            $headers[$sheet][$key_coll] = $single_item;
                        } else {
                            $data[$sheet][$row_key][$key_coll] = $single_item;
                        }

                    } else {
                        if ($row_key == 0) {
                            $headers[$sheet][$key_coll] = 'no_title';
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        }
```

как выловить урл если он там есть?

Answer (score 1):

В общем если кто затупит с похожей ситуацией то ответ прост

```
$worksheet->getHyperlink('H2')->getUrl()
```

но применять нужно на обьект то есть на лист до приведения к массиву
проверить является ли ячейка гиперссылкой можно так же по номеру ячейки `$worksheet->getCell('coords')->hasHyperlink()`